# When a segue is called between two UIViewControllers screen needs to slide from right to left

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Im working on a project which is done in swift 3 and I calls a segue between two view controllers using the method `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Though it directs to the desired `UIViewController`, the screen slides from bottom to top only (by default). My requirement is to make sure the screen slides from right to left once this segue is called. The code is below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.categoryTableView {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBrowsVC", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create custom Presentation.

[Apple Guide][1]


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningCustomPresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH25-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `performSeguewithIdentifier` present viewController with animation like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if tableView == self.categoryTableView {
 let transition = CATransition()
 transition.duration = 0.5
 transition.type = kCATransitionPush
 transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
 view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
 let secVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secViewController") as! secViewController
 secVC.category = home
 present(secVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

In secViewController.swift you should have a variable which you want to pass values

```
class secViewController: UIViewController {
    var category:Bool?
}
```

Comment: Sorry Im new to swift, So am I supposed to give a storyboard ID to my second viewcontroller as "secViewController". Is that what u suggesting ?

Comment: Yes. You should give a storyboard ID to your second View controller and use that storyboardID.

Comment: very small question sir. how do i call this ID in my prepare for segue method ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in `prepareForSegue` method when you are presenting a ViewController. Check updated ans.

Comment: yes sir but i want to pass a state of a boolean to the other ViewController. How would i achieve this. help would much appreciated.

Comment: imagine I have a boolean named "category" in the secViewController, and I wants to pass the state of another boolean named "home" which is in my first ViewController. how would i pass this from firstVC to secVc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137407/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-danutha).

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure your ViewController is embedded in a NavigationController.
2. Ensure you selected Show instead of Present for the segue in storyboard.

Comment: As i have mentioned the segues are between two ViewContollers, but it is not embedded in a NavigationController. So once a row is selected from the first viewcontroller it navigates to the second.

Comment: You have to embed the first ViewController in a NavigationController.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this other than that

Comment: @danutha You can create a Custom Segue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Custom Transitions` for achieving something like this.

Refer to : https://github.com/pgpt10/Custom-Animator on how to implement custom transitioning in a view controller.